# SQL problem Code problem about removing the spam

Tags: sql

Table: Actions

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| user_id       | int     |
| post_id       | int     |
| action_date   | date    |
| action        | enum    |
| extra         | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
```

- There is no primary key for this table
- It may have duplicate rows.
- The action column is an ENUM type of ('view', 'like', 'reaction', 'comment', 'report', 'share').
- The extra column has optional information about the action such as a reason for report or a type of reaction.

Example data:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+
| user_id | post_id | action_date | action | extra  |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+
| 1       | 1       | 2019-07-01  | view   | null   |
| 1       | 1       | 2019-07-01  | like   | null   |
| 1       | 1       | 2019-07-01  | share  | null   |
| 2       | 2       | 2019-07-04  | view   | null   |
| 2       | 2       | 2019-07-04  | report | spam   |
| 3       | 4       | 2019-07-04  | view   | null   |
| 3       | 4       | 2019-07-04  | report | spam   |
| 4       | 3       | 2019-07-02  | view   | null   |
| 4       | 3       | 2019-07-02  | report | spam   |
| 5       | 2       | 2019-07-03  | view   | null   |
| 5       | 2       | 2019-07-03  | report | racism |
| 5       | 5       | 2019-07-03  | view   | null   |
| 5       | 5       | 2019-07-03  | report | racism |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Table: Removals

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| post_id       | int     |
| remove_date   | date    | 
+---------------+---------+
```

- post_id is the primary key of this table.
- Each row in this table indicates that some post was removed as a result of being reported or as a result of an admin review.

Example data:

```
+---------+-------------+
| post_id | remove_date |
+---------+-------------+
| 2       | 2019-07-20  |
| 3       | 2019-07-18  |
+---------+-------------+
```

---

> Write an SQL query to find the average for daily percentage of posts that got removed after being reported as spam, rounded to 2 decimal places.

Example results:

```
+-----------------------+
| average_daily_percent |
+-----------------------+
| 75.00                 |
+-----------------------+
```

- The percentage for 2019-07-04 is 50% because only one post of two spam reported posts was removed.
- The percentage for 2019-07-02 is 100% because one post was reported as spam and it was removed.
- The other days had no spam reports so the average is (50 + 100) / 2 = 75%
- Note that the output is only one number and that we do not care about the remove dates.

My code is below:

```
select round(avg(100*a.rem/b.num),2) as 'average_daily_percent' from

(select count(post_id) as 'rem' from actions
where post_id in (select post_id from removals) and extra= 'spam'
group by action_date) a,

(select count(post_id) as 'num' from actions
where action = 'report' and extra = 'spam'
group by action_date) b
```

May I know why my code is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag) doesn't have `ENUM` data types. What platform is this question regarding?

Comment: Why would days with no removals be ignored rather than counted as `0`?  What if the same post is counted on multiple days as spam before it is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using MySQL.

```
WITH daily_spam_counts AS 
    (SELECT   A.`action_date`, 
              COUNT(*) AS num_posts, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN R.`remove_date` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_posts_removed
        FROM  Actions A
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Removals R ON A.`post_id` = R.`post_id`
        WHERE A.`action` = 'report' 
              AND A.`extra` = 'spam'
        GROUP BY A.`action_date`
     )
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(100 AS float) * Num_posts_removed / num_posts),2) AS average_daily_percent
FROM daily_spam_counts;
```

The first thing it does (within the CTE) is to calculate, for each day,

- how many posts are flagged as spam
- how many of those posts have been removed

The result of the CTE (with your data) is a virtual table as follows

```
action_date  num_posts  num_posts_removed
2019-07-02   1          1
2019-07-04   2          1
```

The second part simply does an average calculation of those across all the relevant days.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9de8714d4aee10ed31ea4017992e987) with it running; note that I added an extra line of spam in the data so that the percentage becomes something with decimal points.

I also wrote this in SQL Server first (then converted to MySQL) so here's a [db<>fiddle in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e517d9313419b414c2cad836ac88896) if you prefer that.